Can two Shiny Application work on same port?
I have deployed two shiny application on cloud via linux machine and on the port XX via IP address of my machine but when i load it only App 1 loads not the App 2, and also the shiny application is loaded in the folder with Ui and Server elements. Can anyone please help with any trouble shoot steps ?
When I load on http://XXXXX.XX:Port It shows both the app but doesnt load app_2

Do you mean on the same port and the same IP? What do expect the behaviour to be? Which app do you expect to appear in the browser? Just specify a different port for the second app using shiny::runApp(app, port = 9999) or whatever.

Yes, both would be the same. I expect both apps to display properly in the browser. I tried to deploy on the server and its already running on the same server so idk how to change the port only for both different.

You need to provide a lot more information. Please see How to write a good R question with a reproducible example It doesn't make sense to have two apps running on the same IP and port. How would the browser know which to connect to? Are you running your own instance of Shiny Server? If so you can specify the port. See this related question.

You can host multiple apps with Shiny server - https://docs.posit.co/shiny-server/#host-a-directory-of-applications.  Perhaps provide a little extra context describing why that would not work with your use case?

In short:
No.
Why?
Simply the problem is that only one program can sit behind a port at a time - think of it as a 1-to-1 dependency. Figuratively speaking, you can think of the IP as a house number and the port as an apartment number. If a high-rise building has several apartments with the same number, you can't tell which apartment you want to go to.
Alternative:
So that on the Internet, for example, several websites with port 80, 8080, ... can be hosted on the same server, there are reverse proxy. This is a program that listens to the port and uses the domain (sub-domains) to determine which website should be addressed. Think of it like a receptionist asking for the name of the occupant of the apartment and telling you to go there.
